# Find the constant $k$ from the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Given:  $$\begin{vmatrix}(b+c)^2 &a^2&a^2\\b^2 &(c+a)^2&b^2 \\c^2&c^2& (a+b)^2\end{vmatrix}=k(abc)(a+b+c)^3$$ Find $k$.

If I directly open the determinant it will go to long I can't apply most of the row or column operation as they keep making it more complex.

Comment: Do you mean this ?$$\begin{vmatrix}(b+c)^2 &a^2&a^2\\b^2 &(c+a)^2&b^2 \\c^2&c^2& (a+b)^2\end{vmatrix}=k(abc)(a+b+c)^3$$

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Why can't you just outright compute the determinant? It will be a little messy, but that just happens sometimes.

Comment: If you are really sure the determinant is of this form, plugging in some values (e.g. $a=b=c=1$) will tell you the answer.

Comment: I'm preparing for exam so I get like 2 minutes per question so I can't take the long way . Putting the values is a good option but I won't be able to it that way in exams

Answer (score 2):

Let $$a=b=c=1$$ and you get the matrix

$$\begin{vmatrix}4&1&1\\1 &4&1 \\1&1& 4\end{vmatrix}=27k$$

The determinant is easily evaluated to be $54$ so $$27k=54$$.

Thus $$k=2$$

Comment: Computationally, you can cut down the work a little if you change $c$ to $-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did not think about that but that would cut the computation significantly.

Comment: Sir where can we use this method to compute the value is it will always work

Comment: Sir why only 1 not any other number

Comment: Any other values will work as well. $1$ sounds like a convenient choice.

Answer (score 0):

It is also simple to compute the posted determinant, $D$ for short, thus ignoring the information on the special form of the result. We are subtracting at the first step the first column from the other two.
$$
\begin{aligned}
D &=
\begin{vmatrix}
(b+c)^2 & a^2 & a^2 \\
b^2 & (c+a)^2 & b^2 \\
c^2 & c^2 & (a+b)^2
\end{vmatrix}
\\[2mm]
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
(b+c)^2 & a^2- (b+c)^2 & a^2 - (b+c)^2 \\
b^2 & (c+a)^2-b^2 & 0 \\
c^2 & 0 & (a+b)^2-c^2
\end{vmatrix}
\\[2mm]
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
(b+c)^2 & a- b-c & a- b-c \\
b^2 & c+a-b & 0 \\
c^2 & 0 & a+b-c
\end{vmatrix}
\cdot(a+b+c)^2
\\[2mm]
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
2bc & -2c & - 2b \\
b^2 & c+a-b & 0 \\
c^2 & 0 & a+b-c
\end{vmatrix}
\cdot(a+b+c)^2
\\[2mm]
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
2bc-bc-bc & -2c & - 2b \\
b^2+\frac b2(c+a-b)+\frac c2\cdot 0 & c+a-b & 0 \\
c^2+\frac c2\cdot 0+\frac c2(a+b-c) & 0 & a+b-c
\end{vmatrix}
\cdot(a+b+c)^2
\\[2mm]
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & -2c & - 2b \\
\frac b2 & c+a-b & 0 \\
\frac c2 & 0 & a+b-c
\end{vmatrix}
\cdot(a+b+c)^3
\\[2mm]
&=
-\begin{vmatrix}
0 & c & b \\
b & c+a-b & 0 \\
c & 0 & a+b-c
\end{vmatrix}
\cdot(a+b+c)^3
\\[2mm]
&=2abc(a+b+c)^3\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(At the last step, using Sarrus, only two out of six terms survive, we can factor $bc$, and $-(a+b-c)-(c+a-b)=-2a$ leads immediately to the result. No step was omitted, symmetry was used when possible.)

---

Computer check:

```
sage: var('a,b,c');
sage: A = matrix(3,3, [(b+c)^2, a^2, a^2, b^2, (a+c)^2, b^2, c^2, c^2, (a+b)^2] )
sage: A.det().factor()
2*(a + b + c)^3*a*b*c
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not long:
$$\prod_{cyc}(a+b)^2+2a^2b^2c^2-\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2(a+b)^2=$$
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(a^4b^2+a^4c^2+2a^3b^3+2a^4bc+2a^3b^2c+2a^3c^2b+2a^2b^2c^2+4a^3b^2c+4a^3c^2b+\tfrac{4}{3}a^2b^2c^2\right)+$$
$$+\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{2}{3}a^2b^2c^2-a^4b^2-a^4c^2-2a^3b^3\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(2a^4bc+6a^3b^2c+6a^3c^2b+4a^2b^2c^2)=2abc(a+b+c)^3.$$
Two minutes of computations! By hand, of course.